# error while deploy using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I got this error:

```
connection failed for: your slave db-server here (SocketError: getaddrinfo:
 Name or service not known), your primary db-server here (SocketError:
 getaddrinfo: Name or service not known), **********.***.** (Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
 Connection refused - connect(2))
```

While typing this command:

```
cap deploy:setup
```

I was using this site http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: `connection failed for: your slave db-server here` sounds like you haven't entered the name or ip of your database server. It won't be able to find 'your slave-db here' because it's not a valid hostname.

Comment: Thanks for help now after entering the name or my database server i get this error   "connection failed for: **********.***.** (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))" How do i solve this error?

Comment: connection refused means the server is not responding. Either it won't accept connections from your machine or it's not installed properly. If I had to guess I'd say your database needs to be configured to listen to more than just local connections.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano uses public and private keys to connect to the database server, even if it's on the same server as the deployed application.  So you need to add the contents of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (where your public key is stored) to your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, but at the end of the line, change the server name to "localhost"